# Using AD Token for access to multiple applications registered in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have chosen Azure AD for authenticating users for the Enterprise Web applications developed using MVC and hosted on Azure Cloud Platform.

We are trying to plan & develop a common portal for the users to which they can login using Azure AD login screen. This Portal will display the links to the cloud applications to which the user has access and they could access the cloud application from this portal.

Please let me know whether this is feasible since I have read in many places that the Azure AD token assigned to the user from Azure AD is valid only for one resource or registered application. Does that mean that when they try to login into another Cloud application registered to the same Azure AD from the portal, they will need to login again or re-use the Azure AD token for the portal in the browser session cookie for logging into the other applications?

Answer (score 2):

It's true that your users authenticate against an application registered in Azure AD and that the issued token is only valid for that application.

However, the user establishes a session with the authorization server (Azure AD) and will not be prompted for credentials when redirected there to authenticate against another registered application.

So your portal page can just contain links to the URLs for the applications. Each application redirects the user to Azure AD for authentication and the user is only prompted for credentials for the first application he/she logs in to.